# How to add custom object to global object cache?

Tags: performance, object-cache

I want to cache a big object in one site collection which will be used across all event receivers and web parts. How can I get the current object of cache. Every example which I found uses Cache keyword (such as this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558270(v=office.14).aspx). But none of them give example how to get the instance of it!!! I don't want to use web properties as this object is very big (contains termset instances and ...)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a safe way to do it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.objectcache.spcacheconfig.aspx